# Select a specific prefix on table depending on a store branch

Tags: php, mysql

I have an interbranch inventory system, meaning that I have three branches. Whenever an admin logged in to the system, it will detect the location of his branch. Here is an example of my code:

```
if ($_SESSION['user_role'] == 'Admin') {
    $execLog = mysqli_query($connection, $queryLog);

    if ($_SESSION['branch'] == 'BS') {

        header("Location: ../admin");

        } elseif ($_SESSION['branch'] == 'TD') {

            header("Location: ../admin");

        } elseif ($_SESSION['branch'] == 'FV') {

            header("Location: ../admin");

        }
```

Each of the branch has a specific prefix for a table on my database. BS is `bs_`, TD is `td_`, and FV `fv_`. Now, my problem is how do I set a query to the specific table in the database without going all through the tables of each admin?

For example, if my branch is BS, I want the queries to be:

```
SELECT * FROM bs_orders;
```

And if my branch is TD, I want the queries to be:

```
SELECT * FROM td_orders
```

How do I achieve this?

Anyway, here is my connectdb.php code

```
<?php 

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "inventorydb";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (!$connection) {
    echo "Failed to connect to the database" . mysqli_errno($connection);
}

?>
```

Comment: what about just doing a string concatenation? set the prefix in a variable and in the query use `FROM $prefix.'_orders'`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised I haven't thought about that.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll wrap it in an answer then so you can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation.

Set the prefix in a variable like this:

```
$prefix= strtolower($_SESSION['branch']);
```

and in the query use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $prefix.'_orders'"
```

Comment: When I echo $sql, it shows `SELECT * FROM bs.'_orders'`. So I used, `{$prefix}` instead of `$prefix.`. It's now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM " . strtolower($_SESSION['branch']) . "_orders";
```